# show notification in jsp page depending on a flag?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have HTML code in the jsp page that I want it to be displayed only after the user submits data and get redirected to this page. So I have to set a success flag as a parameter in the link like:

```
http://site.com/page?success=true
```

Not sending in the request because it will be lost since I am redirecting
I don't want to send it in the link as a parameter and I am thinking of another way
and ideas how to send it? So the link will be:

```
http://site.com/page
```

and I can display the the html code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set it as a request attribtue.

```
if (/* form is succesfully submitted */) {
    request.setAttribute("success", true);
}
request.getRequestDispatcher("page.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Use [JSTL](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) `c:if` tag to conditionally render content based on EL expression.

```
<c:if test="${success}">
    Your notification here.
</c:if>
```

If you want to survive the redirects, then you need to set it as session attribtue instead:

```
if (/* form is succesfully submitted */) {
    request.getSession().setAttribute("success", true);
}
response.sendRedirect("page.jsp");
```

Use `c:remove` remove it after first display so that the subsequent requests won't be affected:

```
<c:if test="${success}">
    <c:remove var="success" scope="session" />
    Your notification here.
</c:if>
```